# kivymd refences with ids

Tags: python, function, kivymd

I'm trying to use the id function to reference text_input from MDTextField, however I can't understand how does the id function works. Does anyone know what is wrong in my code?
The first code is the Main App and the second one is where all the widgets are. I've already searched for a solution in internet, but I can't understand why my code does not work.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from Screen_helper import Home


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='Menu'))
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='Profile'))


class Mainapp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        helper = Builder.load_string(Home)
        screen.add_widget(helper)
        key = self.root.ids.username_input
        return screen


Mainapp().run()
```

```
Home = '''
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'Menu'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: my_button
        text: 'Profile'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Profile'
    MDTextField:
        id: username_input
        input_filter: "int"
        hint_text: 'CHIAVE NUMERICA'
        helper_text: 'compresa tra 0 e 95' 
        helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
        icon_right: 'key-variant'
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.55}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:230
        input_filter: 'int'
        
        
<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'Profile'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Welcome'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Menu' '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an id to the MenuScreen class and then access to the widget.

Add this to the kv file.

```
<MenuScreen>:
    id: menu
```

To access the widget you can now do this in python:

```py
key = self.root.menu.ids.username_input
```

Comment: I’ve tried to add an Id to the class MenuScreen, however it gives me the error:                                                                     AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘MenuScreenID’

Comment: I’ve done as you said, but it it doesn’t work and it gives me the same error

Comment: just realised that you are doing that under the build() function, do it under the on_start() function.